# A problem in solving a PDE of the time-ordered Green function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, greens-functions, non-equilibrium, quantum-transport

In the article written by Jauho in 2006 [Introduction to the Keldysh nonequilibrium Green function technique](http://materias.df.uba.ar/solidosa2012c2/files/2012/07/jauho.pdf), I've tried to operating with whether $g_{k\alpha}^t$ or $g_{k\alpha}^{-1}$ from right to the equation (51)
$$-\mathrm{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial t^\prime}G_{n,k\alpha}^t(t-t^\prime)=\epsilon_kG_{n,k\alpha}^t(t-t^\prime)+\sum_mG_{nm}^t(t-t^\prime)V_{k\alpha,m}^*$$

The article has solved the result of $G_{n,k\alpha}^t$ in equation (52)
$$G_{n,k\alpha}^t(t-t^\prime)=\sum_m\int\mathrm{d}t_1G_{nm}^t(t-t_1)V_{k\alpha,m}^*g_{k\alpha}^t(t_1-t^\prime)$$

However due the result in equation (52) there's no the energy item $\epsilon_k$, I don't know how the first item disappeard in equation (51). After that I consider this is a special integration method make it disappeared, then I ignore the first item of equation (51), however I found that the $g_{k\alpha}^t$ disappeared, the result I solved become
$$G_{n,k\alpha}^t(t-t^\prime)=\mathrm{i}\int\mathrm{d}t_1G_{n,k\alpha}^tg_{k\alpha}^{-1}$$

Also, if I didn't ignore the first item in equation (52), then my result become
$$G_{n,k\alpha}^t(t-t^\prime)=\mathrm{i}\sum_m\int\mathrm{d}t_1\left[\epsilon_kG_{nm}^t(t-t^\prime)V_{k\alpha,m}^*g_{k\alpha}^t+V_{k\alpha}^*G_{nm}^t(t-t^\prime)\right]$$

It's completely different from the result in equation (52), and the imaginary number $\mathrm{i}$ is always there.

All in all, I can't get the result like equation (52). Here I'm grateful to the people who can provide the process of solving equation (51) in detail. The following picture is the part referred above in the article.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green's *functions* are related to *operators*. The functions $G^t_{n,k\alpha}(t-t')$ and $G^t_{nm}(t-t')$ correspond to the operators $G^t_{n,k\alpha}$ and $G^t_{nm}$, which act on the function $f(t)$ and transform it to another functions as follows
$$
(G^t_{n,k\alpha}\ f)(t) = \int\ G^t_{n,k\alpha}(t-t')f(t')\ dt',\quad
(G^t_{nm}\ f)(t) = \int\ G^t_{nm}(t-t')f(t')\ dt'.
$$
It is now clear that equation (51) can be written in operator form
$$
G^t_{n,k\alpha}\ g^{-1}_{k\alpha} = \sum_m G^t_{nm}V^*_{k\alpha,m}, \quad (I)
$$
where $\sum_m$ is the usual sum, $V^*_{k\alpha,m}$ are numerical coefficients and $G^t_{n,k\alpha}\ g^{-1}_{k\alpha}$ is an operator that acts on the function $f(t)$ as follows
$$
(G^t_{n,k\alpha}\ g^{-1}_{k\alpha}\ f)(t) = \int \left(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial t'} - \varepsilon_k\right)G^t_{n,k\alpha}(t-t')\ f(t')\ dt'.
$$
We will consider the operator defined by the last equality as the product of two operators, $G^t_{n,k\alpha}$ ans $g^{-1}_{k\alpha}$. From (I) we now get
$$
G^t_{n,k\alpha} = \sum_m G^t_{nm}V^*_{k\alpha,m}\ g^t_{k\alpha}.\quad (II)
$$
The operator $g^t_{k\alpha}$ is the inverse of the operator $g^{-1}_{k\alpha}$, this operator corresponds to the function $g^t_{k\alpha}(t-t')$. Equation (**), written in terms of functions, coincides with equation (52). From the operator equality $G^t_{n,k\alpha}\ g^{-1}_{k\alpha}\ g^t_{k\alpha} = G^t_{n,k\alpha}$ follows the equation for the function $g^t_{k\alpha}(t-t')$
$$
\int dt_1\ \left(\left(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} - \varepsilon_k\right) G^t_{n,k\alpha}(t-t_1)\right) g^t_{k\alpha}(t_1-t') = G^t_{n,k\alpha}(t-t').
$$
From the last equation we arrive at the following equation for the function $g^t_{k\alpha}(t-t')$
$$
\left(i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \varepsilon_k\right)g^t_{k\alpha}(t-t') = \delta(t-t').
$$
Thus, the function $g^t_{k\alpha}(t-t')$ is itself a (contact?) Green's function and depends on $\varepsilon_k$.

Comment: Thank you, however I still want to know how can I obtain the equation (52) in the picture.

Comment: @Axia But here there is a derivation of formula (52). Do you see that equation (51) can be written in the operator form (I)?  If yes, then you trivially get (II) from (I). Equation (II) is operator form of the equation (52). It is enough to write product of operators in the right hand side of (II) in terms of functions $G^t_{nm}$, $g^t_{k\alpha}$ to get equation (52).

Comment: OK, the problem has been solved. Thank you very much.